# cp: cannot stat `/vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt': No such file or directory

Tags: bash, filenames

I tried a command `cp /vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt .` and I get the error -

```
cp: cannot stat `/vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt': No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I went to cygwin home folder and created the necessary folder structure and text file. I also checked the folder structure and names.

Also, I go into `~/vol/examples/tutorial` and then do `cat science.txt` and I can read the document. Then why does the CP command not work ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do this and you will understand:

```
cd ~/vol/examples/tutorial 
pwd
```

most likely the result of pwd is not just `/vol/examples/tutorial` but `/home/username/vol/examples/tutorial`

~ is replaced by the user home directory, usually and even under cygiwn /home.

Comment: yes, it is /home/username/vol/examples/tutorial. I did cat ~/vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt and I can see the text file. But, I don't understand why all these errors happened. I am reading this tutorial at - http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unix2.html

Comment: because when you use cp /vol is not the same as cp ~/vol.
change your cp command to cp ~/vol/ to work. It is not a problem, you are providing different paths